# Java and Linux OS hangs randomly for 24 minutes (Linux, arm, Debian, Java 7 ARM)

Tags: java, linux, debugging, jvm, arm

### *Background/context:*

We are running Java application on one of CompuLab CoM:

```
https://compulab.co.il/products/computer-on-modules/cm-fx6/#overview
```

JVM version: Oracle Java 7 ARM 1.7.0_60

OS reference:

```
http://www.compulab.co.il/workspace/mediawiki/index.php5/CM-FX6_Linux
```

The application is not trivial: lots of threads, access to Ethernet (LAN), serial interface, GPRS/UMTS modem, access to Internet (ppp deamon), GPS, touch screen, database (SQLite), file system. In other words use OS resources extensively.....

We are observing that Java application (all of its threads) and OS basic functionality randomly hangs. I would say it is a Linux kernel bug but by killing the Java application it recovers and operates normally.

***This state always takes exactly 24 minutes. Afterwards it recovers and behaves normally. Average rate of occurrence is once per 24-30 hours.***

When it happens, externally invoked events like messages sent to application via Ethernet or serial interface are buffered (by OS probably) and all of them are processed immediately after it recovers.

When I establish SSH connection to device in advance, after it happens the connection is either blocked (all command are buffered and processed after it recovers - 24 mintes) or its working, than:

- basic OS utilities does not work:  "top" for example
- *jstack -F* does not work, just hangs and does not produce any output
- ***killing Java application by kill -9 PID released the OS and everything starts to operate normally***

While it is in this state, the OS each time behaves differently. Other findings:

- Basic network based utilities does not work (SSH, FTP) – can not
  establish new connection to OS from another machine.
- PING from another machine does work until I unplug an plug Ethernet
  cable from device, sometimes PING than stops working
- ***Sometimes OS system time hangs as well (not always), after 24 minutes
  it continues delayed for 24 minutes.***
- New USB input devices (mouse, keyboard) can not be connected while in
  that state (happens always).

**Another strange thing:**

A touch screen is used for interaction with a user (driver compiled as kernel module). And it works even while it is hung. Java application (GUI Swing) can handle events like pressing button so I can run some code behind button click handler.
It seems like all threads are blocked but Java Swing can handle some input events and our application precesses them until it needs to interact with already blocked threads or OS (run bash script on button click) or call sleep method. Than it hangs as well.
In other words, the Java application is hung ”partially” - can still handle something.

### **Already tried:**

- Tools for JVM remote debugging: Java Mission Control, VisualVM.
  Connection was also established before it hung. Everything seemed OK
  in terms of thread dump, heap dump etc. (I can send by e-mail). Even
  the connection remained and I could see in thees tools that processor
  usage dropped to 0 % for JVM.
- jstack -F  (via SSH): does not work, just hangs and does not produce
  any output
- I tried to run OS without the driver for touch screen and it still
  happened.
- I tried to run two parallel Java application. One of them was very
  simple – just writing to log timestamps. And both of them hung.
- I tried to run System.exit(0) in terms of button click handler while
  app. and all threads hung and it does not worked (hung as well)

### **Questions:**

Is it Linux kernel bug or JVM (its ARM implementation) bug?

Is Java (JVM) able to hang and block basic OS functionality (FTP, SSH, system time, other utilities)?

How can I further diagnose/debug this issue when basic utilities like jstack -F does not work?

Do you have any ideas what could be the cause of this issue and why it always recovers exactly after 24 minutes?

### Update 1: 2014-07-10

Finally I manage to “catch” this weird state again. Here are my further findings.

Based on *nos* suggestion I tried run via ssh (established in advanced):

```
*strace -f -p PID*
```

***Unfortunately the bash script command hung as well (same behavior like with jstack).***

As far as the user limit (ulimit) and OS resources are concerned, bellow I report figures taken **just after the system recovered from last hung**. At that state it had been running for  **24 hours** and I can confirm that those figures remain roughly the same during long-term operation (no random peeks during operation). From my point of view, they are **ok** and application is not stepping over any resource or other limit in any way.

**Java current heap**

*Used: 18 MB, Free: 12 MB, Total: 30 MB, Max: 230 MB*

**Java heap**

```
 root@cm-debian:~# /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_60/bin/jmap -heap 3242
Attaching to process ID 3242, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Client compiler detected.
JVM version is 24.60-b09

using thread-local object allocation.
Mark Sweep Compact GC

Heap Configuration:
   MinHeapFreeRatio = 40
   MaxHeapFreeRatio = 70
   MaxHeapSize      = 249561088 (238.0MB)
   NewSize          = 1048576 (1.0MB)
   MaxNewSize       = 4294836224 (4095.875MB)
   OldSize          = 4194304 (4.0MB)
   NewRatio         = 2
   SurvivorRatio    = 8
   PermSize         = 12582912 (12.0MB)
   MaxPermSize      = 67108864 (64.0MB)
   G1HeapRegionSize = 0 (0.0MB)

Heap Usage:
New Generation (Eden + 1 Survivor Space):
   capacity = 10092544 (9.625MB)
   used     = 6772088 (6.458366394042969MB)
   free     = 3320456 (3.1666336059570312MB)
   67.09991058745942% used
Eden Space:
   capacity = 9043968 (8.625MB)
   used     = 6620336 (6.3136444091796875MB)
   free     = 2423632 (2.3113555908203125MB)
   73.2016743093297% used
From Space:
   capacity = 1048576 (1.0MB)
   used     = 151752 (0.14472198486328125MB)
   free     = 896824 (0.8552780151367188MB)
   14.472198486328125% used
To Space:
   capacity = 1048576 (1.0MB)
   used     = 0 (0.0MB)
   free     = 1048576 (1.0MB)
   0.0% used
tenured generation:
   capacity = 22134784 (21.109375MB)
   used     = 17650936 (16.83324432373047MB)
   free     = 4483848 (4.276130676269531MB)
   79.7429782915433% used
Perm Generation:
   capacity = 19136512 (18.25MB)
   used     = 19023016 (18.141761779785156MB)
   free     = 113496 (0.10823822021484375MB)
   99.40691386183647% used

9597 interned Strings occupying 729344 bytes.
```

**top**

```
top - 11:41:29 up 21:59,  2 users,  load average: 1.51, 1.25, 1.22
Tasks:  93 total,   1 running,  92 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  9.4%us,  8.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 82.5%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:    966780k total,   273080k used,   693700k free,    27216k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,   126352k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                             
 3242 root      20   0  398m  79m  11m S 23.6  8.4 346:16.82 java                                                                                
 3889 root      20   0  2804 1096  848 R  5.5  0.1   0:00.07 top                                                                                 
    1 root      20   0  2124  688  596 S  0.0  0.1   0:02.92 init                                                                                
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.03 kthreadd                                                                            
    3 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:14.32 ksoftirqd/0                                                                         
    5 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.14 kworker/u:0                                                                         
    6 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/0                                                                         
    7 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 khelper
```

**java limits**

```
root@cm-debian:~# java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep -iE 'HeapSize|PermSize|ThreadStackSize'
    uintx AdaptivePermSizeWeight                    = 20              {product}           
     intx CompilerThreadStackSize                   = 0               {pd product}        
    uintx ErgoHeapSizeLimit                         = 0               {product}           
    uintx HeapSizePerGCThread                       = 67108864        {product}           
    uintx InitialHeapSize                          := 15468480        {product}           
    uintx LargePageHeapSizeThreshold                = 134217728       {product}           
    uintx MaxHeapSize                              := 249561088       {product}           
    uintx MaxPermSize                               = 67108864        {pd product}        
    uintx PermSize                                  = 12582912        {pd product}        
     intx ThreadStackSize                           = 320             {pd product}        
     intx VMThreadStackSize                         = 512             {pd product}        
java version "1.7.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_60-b19)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.60-b09, mixed mode)
```

**process limits**

```
root@cm-debian:~# cat /proc/3242/limits
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units     
Max cpu time              unlimited            unlimited            seconds   
Max file size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max data size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max stack size            8388608              unlimited            bytes     
Max core file size        0                    unlimited            bytes     
Max resident set          unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max processes             unlimited            unlimited            processes 
Max open files            8192                 8192                 files     
Max locked memory         65536                65536                bytes     
Max address space         unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max file locks            unlimited            unlimited            locks     
Max pending signals       16382                16382                signals   
Max msgqueue size         819200               819200               bytes     
Max nice priority         0                    0                    
Max realtime priority     0                    0                    
Max realtime timeout      unlimited            unlimited            us
```

**system memory info**

```
root@cm-debian:~# cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:         966780 kB
MemFree:          694312 kB
Buffers:           27384 kB
Cached:           126364 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:           140748 kB
Inactive:         107684 kB
Active(anon):      94992 kB
Inactive(anon):     2064 kB
Active(file):      45756 kB
Inactive(file):   105620 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
HighTotal:        524288 kB
HighFree:         301088 kB
LowTotal:         442492 kB
LowFree:          393224 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:                 0 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:         94692 kB
Mapped:            21220 kB
Shmem:              2376 kB
Slab:              13268 kB
SReclaimable:       5284 kB
SUnreclaim:         7984 kB
KernelStack:         960 kB
PageTables:          980 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:      483388 kB
Committed_AS:     137260 kB
VmallocTotal:     286720 kB
VmallocUsed:        2928 kB
VmallocChunk:     283040 kB


root@cm-debian:~# vmstat -s
       966780 K total memory
       272468 K used memory
       140776 K active memory
       107712 K inactive memory
       694312 K free memory
        27392 K buffer memory
       126404 K swap cache
            0 K total swap
            0 K used swap
            0 K free swap
       726963 non-nice user cpu ticks
            0 nice user cpu ticks
       621187 system cpu ticks
      6371123 idle cpu ticks
         3683 IO-wait cpu ticks
          324 IRQ cpu ticks
         2146 softirq cpu ticks
            0 stolen cpu ticks
       130871 pages paged in
        97520 pages paged out
            0 pages swapped in
            0 pages swapped out
    293822206 interrupts
    494034482 CPU context switches
   1412595732 boot time
         3916 forks
```

**threads**

```
root@cm-debian:~# cat /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max
32768

root@cm-debian:~# cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max
15102

root@cm-debian:~# cat /proc/sys/vm/max_map_count
65530


root@cm-debian:~# ls -l /proc/3242/task/ | wc -l
33

root@cm-debian:~# ps huH p 3242 | wc -l
32

root@cm-debian:~# grep -s '^Threads' /proc/[0-9]*/status | awk '{ sum += $2; } END { print sum; }'
122
```

**open files / file descriptors**

```
root@cm-debian:~# ls -l /proc/3242/fd | wc -l
81
```

### Update 2: 2014-13-10

This time I logged all Java threads stack traces while the OS was hung (as I stated previously, the touch screen and its events still works so I wrote stack traces to log file in terms of UI button handler).

From my point of view, **all threads are in “correct” state** (sleeping, waiting for UDP datagram etc..) and **it is obvious that the hang is not caused by a Java application SW operation which would took 24 minutes**.

```
10:49:42,293> [INFO ] THREAD stack traces: 
****************************************

ID: 56, name: Mpg123AudioPlayer_PASSENGER_ctrlLoop
java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:340)
java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.sleep(TimeUnit.java:360)
epis5fcc.audio.mpg.MpgAudioOutputPlayer.ctrlLoop(MpgAudioOutputPlayer.java:169)
epis5fcc.audio.mpg.MpgAudioOutputPlayer.access$000(MpgAudioOutputPlayer.java:19)
epis5fcc.audio.mpg.MpgAudioOutputPlayer$1.run(MpgAudioOutputPlayer.java:88)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

ID: 11, name: AWT-EventQueue-0
java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1589)
epis5fcc.domain.debug.ThreadStackTracesLogger.log(ThreadStackTracesLogger.java:30)
epis5fcc.ui.settings.FccRegistryScreen$7.actionPerformed(FccRegistryScreen.java:303)
javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)

ID: 34, name: Mpg123AudioPlayer_DRIVER_ctrlLoop
java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:340)
java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.sleep(TimeUnit.java:360)
epis5fcc.audio.mpg.MpgAudioOutputPlayer.ctrlLoop(MpgAudioOutputPlayer.java:169)
epis5fcc.audio.mpg.MpgAudioOutputPlayer.access$000(MpgAudioOutputPlayer.java:19)
epis5fcc.audio.mpg.MpgAudioOutputPlayer$1.run(MpgAudioOutputPlayer.java:88)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

ID: 26, name: IOTxUdpAccessLoop_IODispatchAccess
java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
jCommons.comm.io.access.IOUdpAccess.transmitLoop(IOUdpAccess.java:114)
jCommons.comm.io.access.IOAccessBase$2.run(IOAccessBase.java:50)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

ID: 29, name: MasterLoop_main
java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
jCommons.master.MasterLoop.ctrlLoop(MasterLoop.java:87)
jCommons.master.MasterLoop.access$000(MasterLoop.java:11)
jCommons.master.MasterLoop$1.run(MasterLoop.java:58)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

ID: 27, name: IORxSerialPortAccessPollLoop_IOModemAccess
java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
jCommons.comm.io.access.IOSerialPortAccessPoll.reciveLoop(IOSerialPortAccessPoll.java:256)
jCommons.comm.io.access.IOAccessBase$1.run(IOAccessBase.java:43)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

ID: 31, name: UsbUpdateWatchService_ctrlLoop
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.takeFirst(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:489)
java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.take(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:678)
sun.nio.fs.AbstractWatchService.take(AbstractWatchService.java:118)
jCommons.update.usb.UsbUpdateWatchService.ctrlLoop(UsbUpdateWatchService.java:107)
jCommons.update.usb.UsbUpdateWatchService.access$000(UsbUpdateWatchService.java:25)
jCommons.update.usb.UsbUpdateWatchService$1.run(UsbUpdateWatchService.java:75)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

ID: 25, name: IORxUdpAccessLoop_IODispatchAccess
java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive0(Native Method)
java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive(AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:145)
java.net.DatagramSocket.receive(DatagramSocket.java:786)
jCommons.comm.io.access.IOUdpAccess.reciveLoop(IOUdpAccess.java:175)
jCommons.comm.io.access.IOAccessBase$1.run(IOAccessBase.java:43)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

ID: 2, name: Reference Handler
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:133)

ID: 30, name: VehicleCtrl_ctrlLoop
java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
epis5fcc.domain.vehicle.control.VehicleCtrl.ctrlLoop(VehicleCtrl.java:74)
jCommons.comm.protocol.ProtCtrlBase$1.run(ProtCtrlBase.java:24)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

ID: 35, name: Mpg123AudioPlayer_INNER_ctrlLoop
java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:340)
java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.sleep(TimeUnit.java:360)
epis5fcc.audio.mpg.MpgAudioOutputPlayer.ctrlLoop(MpgAudioOutputPlayer.java:169)
epis5fcc.audio.mpg.MpgAudioOutputPlayer.access$000(MpgAudioOutputPlayer.java:19)
epis5fcc.audio.mpg.MpgAudioOutputPlayer$1.run(MpgAudioOutputPlayer.java:88)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


ID: 21, name: IORxSerialPortAccessPollLoop_IOFccAccess
java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
jCommons.comm.io.access.IOSerialPortAccessPoll.reciveLoop(IOSerialPortAccessPoll.java:256)
jCommons.comm.io.access.IOAccessBase$1.run(IOAccessBase.java:43)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

ID: 7, name: FileWatchdog
java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
org.apache.log4j.helpers.FileWatchdog.run(FileWatchdog.java:104)


ID: 8, name: Java2D Disposer
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)
sun.java2d.Disposer.run(Disposer.java:145)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

ID: 17, name: com.google.inject.internal.util.$Finalizer
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)
com.google.inject.internal.util.$Finalizer.run(Finalizer.java:114)

ID: 10, name: AWT-XAWT
sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.waitForEvents(Native Method)
sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.run(XToolkit.java:541)
sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.run(XToolkit.java:505)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

ID: 32, name: Thread-4
sun.nio.fs.LinuxWatchService.poll(Native Method)
sun.nio.fs.LinuxWatchService.access$600(LinuxWatchService.java:47)
sun.nio.fs.LinuxWatchService$Poller.run(LinuxWatchService.java:311)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

ID: 28, name: IOTxSerialPortAccessPollLoop_IOModemAccess
java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
jCommons.comm.io.access.IOSerialPortAccessPoll.transmitLoop(IOSerialPortAccessPoll.java:187)
jCommons.comm.io.access.IOAccessBase$2.run(IOAccessBase.java:50)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

ID: 14, name: DestroyJavaVM

ID: 22, name: IOTxSerialPortAccessPollLoop_IOFccAccess
java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
jCommons.comm.io.access.IOSerialPortAccessPoll.transmitLoop(IOSerialPortAccessPoll.java:187)
jCommons.comm.io.access.IOAccessBase$2.run(IOAccessBase.java:50)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

ID: 19, name: TimerQueue
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2082)
java.util.concurrent.DelayQueue.take(DelayQueue.java:220)
javax.swing.TimerQueue.run(TimerQueue.java:171)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

ID: 12, name: AWT-Shutdown
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
sun.awt.AWTAutoShutdown.run(AWTAutoShutdown.java:296)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

ID: 23, name: IORxUdpAccessLoop_IOCityScrnAccess
java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive0(Native Method)
java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive(AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:145)
java.net.DatagramSocket.receive(DatagramSocket.java:786)
jCommons.comm.io.access.IOUdpAccess.reciveLoop(IOUdpAccess.java:175)
jCommons.comm.io.access.IOAccessBase$1.run(IOAccessBase.java:43)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

ID: 3, name: Finalizer
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)
java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:209)

ID: 4, name: Signal Dispatcher

ID: 52, name: pool-3-thread-1
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

ID: 24, name: IOTxUdpAccessLoop_IOCityScrnAccess
java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
jCommons.comm.io.access.IOUdpAccess.transmitLoop(IOUdpAccess.java:114)
jCommons.comm.io.access.IOAccessBase$2.run(IOAccessBase.java:50)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

ID: 36, name: RemoteUpdateCtrl_ctrlLoop
java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
epis5fcc.domain.update.remote.RemoteUpdateCtrl.ctrlLoop(RemoteUpdateCtrl.java:94)
jCommons.comm.protocol.ProtCtrlBase$1.run(ProtCtrlBase.java:24)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

ID: 55, name: Mpg123AudioPlayer_OUTER_ctrlLoop
java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:340)
java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.sleep(TimeUnit.java:360)
epis5fcc.audio.mpg.MpgAudioOutputPlayer.ctrlLoop(MpgAudioOutputPlayer.java:169)
epis5fcc.audio.mpg.MpgAudioOutputPlayer.access$000(MpgAudioOutputPlayer.java:19)
epis5fcc.audio.mpg.MpgAudioOutputPlayer$1.run(MpgAudioOutputPlayer.java:88)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: A JVM should not be able to hang the OS in this manner - if anything it's a kernel bug. Can you strace the jvm process (run strace -f -p pid_of_java) ? Is memory use by the JVM excessive , i.e. is it swapping ?

Comment: Even if JVM provokes such issues, it is quite unlikely to be the root problem. JVM is a regular process which does nothing illegal to the OS (I can tell so since I was actually involved in HotSpot/ARM development). Next time when it hangs, try to connect to JVM with `gdb` and get native stack traces.

Comment: I agree the JVM shouldn't be able to hang the OS like this.  But I'd perhaps check 'ulimit -a' on the system and see if the Java process could be exhausting any of those.

Comment: Thank you all: @apangin for your suggestions. Unfortunately it did not help to solve the problem. Please see my Update 1. Any other ideas?

Comment: To @nos: thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately it did not help to solve the problem. Please see my Update 1. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appear to be a problem related with GPT and local timers simultaneous use.

On Freescale community you can see [one](https://community.freescale.com/message/431843#431843) more question similar to yours and [other](https://community.freescale.com/thread/315428) from someone given some clarification.

For the resolution, apply this [patch](https://community.freescale.com/message/381607#381607).

From the [second post](https://community.freescale.com/message/381670#381670) you can jump to kernel 3.10.17 from Fresscale or 3.13.3 from kernel.org

Currently I am trying the patch to see if resolves a similar problem.